# Re-rendering ng-repeat after the array is updated by controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to perform a `pagination` and I'm facing the issue that the `page numbers` isn't updated when the array gets updated.

I've searched a lot about this but I couldn't find a working solution for my problem.

I have the following `code`:

**JS:**

```
$scope.nextPendingReturnsPage = function(next) {
  if (next != $scope.pendingReturnsPageCount) {
    $scope.showPendingReturnsPaginate.range = setNextPageRange(next);
  }
};

var setNextPageRange = function(prevPage) {
  var range = [];
  var limit = null;
  if ($scope.pendingReturnsPageCount - prevPage > 10) {
    limit = 10;
  } else limit = $scope.pendingReturnsPageCount - prevPage;

  for (var i = prevPage + 1; i <= limit + 10; i++) {
    range.push(i);
  };
  return range;    
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<li ng-repeat="i in showPendingReturnsPaginate.range track by i" ng-click=""><a href='#'>{{$index+1}}</a></li>
```

**PS:** I tried to use `$scope.$apply()`, but it doesn't work, I just got that `$scope.$apply()` is already in progress error.

Comment: Are you sure `setNextPageRange(next)` returns correctly? you should also define `setNextPageRange` before you use it.

Comment: yea it is returning properly

Comment: Create a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/) that reproduces your issue.